# Stripe Connect : Create Account issue

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm facing the below issue when creating an Account from Stripe Dashboard > Connect > Account > Create.

```
Custom accounts are currently in private beta in your country (IN); contact sales+IN@stripe.com if you'd like to be notified when this is available
```

Comment: I think you need to contact sales+IN@stripe.com. SO is a platform to ask programming related questions.

Comment: @stud3nt It's related to Stripe Configuration also

Comment: Please share the configuration you are using in the question.

Comment: If you're trying it for an Indian Application then it won't let you because Stripe Connect is not available in India yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying it for an Indian Application then it won't let you because Stripe Connect is not available in India yet.

If the Application you're working on is based on a country where Stripe Connect is supported then you might have set the country of your Stripe Account to India.

In Short, If you are trying it for an Indian Application, It won't work. If you're trying it for An Application that is based on Some other country AND if that country Supports Stripe Connect and still it's not working then you must've set the Country of the Stripe Account to India.